# Analysis of messages sent (method invocations) within a ruby application?

Tags: ruby, oop, graph, profiling

Is there a tool that analyzes the messages that are sent to objects (i.e. method invocations) within a ruby application?

Ideally the tool would create a (GraphViz) diagram and is able filter classes in the results (f.i. monitor only classes specific to the application instead of all classes like String, Array and the lot).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have dtrace support, [rubyprof](http://ruby-prof.rubyforge.org) is the next best thing.

As for graphing, you may have to use an auxiliary analysis package of some sort to get the kinds of results you want.